# How to edit the linux command output string in shell script?

Tags: linux, sh

There is a command 'netcfg' which is equivalent to 'ifconfig' which list out the interfaces. 
The output of the 'netcfg' command is something like below

```
lo       up     127.0.0.1/8 0x0000049 23:45:12:11:43:54
dummy0   DOWN   0.0.0.0     0x0000078 11:22:44:55:21:98
p2p0     UP     0.0.0.0     0x0000078 11:22:44:55:21:98
ppp0     UP     192.168.3.4 0x0000054 34:54:88:94:22:FF
```

I need to run the command 'netcfg' in the shell script and need to check if ppp0 interface is up. Can anybody please give some idea how to do it in shell script in linux?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netcfg | grep -c -e '^ppp0\s*UP'` will print 1 and will set $? to 0 if the ppp0 is UP. will print 0 and and will set $? to 1 if ppp0 is DOWN or not present in the netcfg output.

update, working on android:

```
$ adb shell
shell@hammerhead:/ $ netcfg | grep -c -e '^lo[[:space:]]*UP'
1
shell@hammerhead:/ $
```

Comment: I like your answer better. :)

Comment: For scripts, `grep -q` is probably more useful than `grep -c`.

Comment: Please find the attached screeshot

Comment: Looks like you are running on android.  I bet your grep is not as functional as expected -- perhaps not recognizing \s, maybe [[:space:]] would work instead?

Comment: i am completely new to shell script. I am unable to know how to use that space. i would be greatful if you can post the complete command :)

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi we are all new to something at some point, doesn't really mean we all skip doing our homework. your problem of "not working for me" is just a matter of syntax. you could google it out in no time just by "grep" "expression" "spaces". I wonder if you have been waiting 7 hours to get the answer.

Comment: @MichaelTabolsky sorry for that really. Now the command with :space: works correctly. But a small problem. When I use it in script it gives output 1. When i check in shell script with if [ "$?" = "1" ] it fails. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi explain "fails". keep oin mind that the value returned value in this case is "inverted". 0 means "success, found" and 1 means "did not find any of that"

Answer (score 1):

```
X=`netcfg | grep ppp0 | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$X" == "UP" ]; then
   echo "ppp0 is UP!"
fi
```

Comment: You have a [useless use of `grep`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep) there.  `netcfg | awk '/ppp0/ { print $2 }'`

Comment: Or maybe say `netcfg | awk '/ppp0/ { if ($2 == "UP") print "y"; else print "n"; }'`.